# Stop Sublime Linter from linting my .erb files

Tags: package, erb, sublimetext2, lint

How can I prevent the Sublime Linter package for Sublime Text linting files with an erb extension?

Comment: You can disable linters by name using "sublimelinter_disable" setting but not by extension.

Comment: Perhaps you can change the syntax associated to ERB files so the linter does not run on it. Per example "Ruby on Rails" files are linted because it is defined in the "sublimelinter_syntax_map" setting.

Comment: @aanton Thanks for the suggestion. However I've tried removing ruby_on_rails from the syntax map in the user settings, but it has no effect.

Comment: Are your ERB file associated to "Ruby on Rails" syntax and you have removed "Ruby on Rails": "ruby" from sublimelinter_syntax_map setting? Try to reopen the file. My advice is only edit "Settings - User" preferences (in this case "Preferences - Packages Settings - SublimeLinter - Settings User")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick based on changing the syntax associated to ERB files.

1. Clone the current syntax file of your ERB files. Look for the the .tmLanguage files (i suppose you are using one located in Packages/Rails or Packages/Ruby folders) and copy it to the Packages/User folder. Edit the copied file, look for "name" and change the following line to change the displayed name (pe. User ERB). My advice is rename the file too :)
2. Change the syntax associated to your ERB files. Map them to the new syntax created.

The new syntax is not mapped into the SublimeLinter settings so the linter will not run.

I have tested the trick and works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Linting can be disabled by extension in the current version of SublimeLinter. Check the docs at http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/settings.html#user-settings.

Example: I've chosen to highlight bitbake files with python highlighting, and changed the flake8 linter in Packages/User/SublimeLinter.sublime-settings.

```
"flake8": {
    "@disable": false,
    "args": [],
    "builtins": "",
    "excludes": ["*/*.bb", "*/*.bbappend"],
    "ignore": "",
    "max-complexity": -1,
    "max-line-length": null,
    "select": ""
},
```